# Adding data text file to apigee database

Tags: javascript, node.js, apigee

I am trying to add data to apigee database from text files. I have several text files which contain books data.

I am able to add one book data by this code:

```
    function saveData(){
    //Initialize our client
    var client = new Usergrid.Client({
        orgName:"orgname",
        appName:"sandbox"
    });

    //In our options object we set the type of the entitiy
    //and we also set any data that goes along with it
    //in this case it's the books title.
    var options = {
        type:"book",
        title:"someTitle",
        author:"someAuthor",
        newElement:"Value"
    };

    //Let's create our entity, and display the results
    //of the creation in the html element with the id of response
    client.createEntity(options, function(error, book){
        if(error) {
            //error saving book
            $("#response").append("There was an error!");
            alert("Error");         
        } else {
            var uuid = book.get("uuid");
            var author = book.get("author");
            var title =  book.get("title");
            $("#response").append("Book saved! Its uuid on our server is: "+uuid+"<br/>");
            $("#response").append("The book you saved was: "+title + "<br/>");
            $("#response").append("It's author is: "+author);
            alert("Its working");            
        }
    }); 
}
saveData()
```

How do I access the .txt files and get data of other books from javascript?
I understand that javascript only allows adding files through user input using FileReader(). Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear.  Are you trying to read a TXT file from Node.js?  If so, your question is not specific to Apigee.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will not generate any .txt files, but to read the saved book entity back, you would do something like this:

```
      books.fetch(
                function(err, data) { // Success
                    if (err) {
                        alert("read failed");
                    } else {
                        while(books.hasNextEntity()) {
                            var book = books.getNextEntity();
                            alert(book.get("title")); // Output the title of the book
                        }
                    }
                });
```